# Android canvas.drawBitmap draws very bad images. What is the best way to optimize them?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, widget, android-canvas

I'm writing a widget drawing a combination of images by canvas.

If I decode a bitmap and draw it I get a very bad image.

I use this code to do this:

```
int widht = 100;
int heigt = 100;

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.square), widht, heigt, true);

Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(widht, heigt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, paint);
```

Do I have to set paint in a different way?

Comment: Use a bigger original image and also try options.inScaled = false when loadig your bitmap

Comment: Thanks  for the answer, but if the option inScaled = false do not permit the resize of the image. All the original images that I use are bigger.

Comment: If you are scaling down then this is another story because some other people complained about quality too and we could not find the solution at that time. One can try using different sizes of the original image...

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on a screen that your app isn't set up to support?

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```